OpenTelemetry Collector remove the outer body element of the journald fields
The OpenTelemetry Collector configuration:
receivers:
  journald:

processors:
  resource:
    attributes:
    - key: loki.format
      value: json
      action: insert
    - key: deployment.environment
      value: "dev"
      action: insert

exporters:
  loki:
    endpoint: "https://loki.net/loki/api/v1/push"
    sending_queue:
      num_consumers: 5
      queue_size: 10000
    headers:
      "X-Scope-OrgID": "index"
  file:
    path: /home/otelcol-contrib/temp.log

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers: [journald]
      processors: [resource]
      exporters: [loki]

Serializes out a JSON object to Loki that looks like this:
{
  "resourceLogs": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "loki.format",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "json"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "deployment.environment",
            "value": {
              "stringValue": "dev"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "scopeLogs": [
        {
          "scope": {},
          "logRecords": [
            {
              "timeUnixNano": "1721831731222344000",
              "observedTimeUnixNano": "1721831731422059659",
              "body": {
                "kvlistValue": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "key": "_SELINUX_CONTEXT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "unconfined\n"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_SLICE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "system.slice"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_HOSTNAME",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "hostname-dev"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/system.slice/otelcol-contrib.service"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_CAP_EFFECTIVE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "0"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_PID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "2262330"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "SYSLOG_FACILITY",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "3"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_EXE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/usr/bin/otelcol-contrib"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "PRIORITY",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "6"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "otelcol-contrib"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_TRANSPORT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "stdout"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_UNIT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "otelcol-contrib.service"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_UID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "997"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "231cd2139b2f4664b755d43b4690aef0"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_GID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "997"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_STREAM_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "8a194d71567d4ae4b4752a9f132eb336"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_MACHINE_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "5fca68f59b9583a46efa7b9f6697ef74"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_BOOT_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "f0d1b58e375844c3961c527ffc365e6c"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_CMDLINE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/usr/bin/otelcol-contrib --config=/etc/otelcol- contrib/config.yaml"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "598265666336"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_COMM",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "otelcol-contrib"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "MESSAGE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "2024-07-24T14:35:31.222Z\tinfo\tservice@v0.104.0/service.go:270\tShutdown complete."
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "__CURSOR",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "s=92ed14a0f4d04f8f9b315bb73d09e814;i=20f19;b=f0d1b58e375844c3961c527ffc365e6c;m=8b4b699b20;t=61dff30b3d748;x=3a5de1616420ef73"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "traceId": "",
              "spanId": ""
            },
            {
              "timeUnixNano": "1721831731241174000",
              "observedTimeUnixNano": "1721831731422135940",
              "body": {
                "kvlistValue": {
                  "values": [
                    {
                      "key": "UNIT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "otelcol-contrib.service"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "CODE_FUNC",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "unit_log_success"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_MACHINE_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "5fca68f59b9583a46efa7b9f6697ef74"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SELINUX_CONTEXT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "unconfined\n"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_SLICE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "-.slice"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_UID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "0"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "TID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "MESSAGE_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "7ad2d189f7e94e70a38c781354912448"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_TRANSPORT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "journal"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "SYSLOG_FACILITY",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "3"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_CAP_EFFECTIVE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "1ffffffffff"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_CMDLINE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/lib/systemd/systemd autoinstall --system --deserialize 41"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "systemd"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "598265685166"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_BOOT_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "f0d1b58e375844c3961c527ffc365e6c"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "1721831731241074"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "__CURSOR",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "s=92ed14a0f4d04f8f9b315bb73d09e814;i=20f1a;b=f0d1b58e375844c3961c527ffc365e6c;m=8b4b69e4ae;t=61dff30b420d6;x=d6baded09f1b919b"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_EXE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_PID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "1"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "/init.scope"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "PRIORITY",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "6"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_SYSTEMD_UNIT",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "init.scope"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_GID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "0"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "INVOCATION_ID",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "231cd2139b2f4664b755d43b4690aef0"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_HOSTNAME",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "hostname-dev"
                          }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "_COMM",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "systemd"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "CODE_LINE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "5553"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "MESSAGE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "otelcol-contrib.service: Deactivated successfully."
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key": "CODE_FILE",
                      "value": {
                        "stringValue": "src/core/unit.c"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
              "traceId": "",
              "spanId": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

These log lines turn up in a Telegraph Loki dashboard correctly but each field is prepended with the "body" string due to journald field key/value pairs being nested under "body" outer element in the json log.

Is there a way to cause the fields to not be nested under the body element to render the log lines in Grafana correctly and for field names to not become prepended?
